ScreenSaverDefaults not working for screensaver
I’m creating an application which shows a bunch of lights blinking on and off randomly, and early on I created a screensaver target as well.  The lights blink properly on macOS, iOS, iPadOS, and in the screensaver.  I have settings (at the moment, the time interval of blinking), set through a settings view, working properly in the macOS application, on iOS, and on iPadOS.  For the screensaver, the settings view shows up properly in the Settings application, and changes in the settings view show up obediently in the screensaver preview—and then they are ignored when the screensaver is activated.
I have included my user settings class below.  It uses UserDefaults on iOS and iPadOS and ScreenSaverDefaults on macOS, including for the screensaver.  The exact same code which is failing somehow in the screensaver works fine in other contexts on macOS.
Does anyone have any idea why there would be any difference?  Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
#if os(macOS)
import ScreenSaver
#endif

fileprivate let timerIntervalKey = "timerInterval"

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = UserSettings()
    
    func double(forKey: String) -> Double {
        return defaults.double(forKey: forKey)
    }
    
    func set(_ value: Double, forKey: String) {
        defaults.set(value, forKey: forKey)
    }

    @Published var timerInterval: TimeInterval {
        didSet {
            defaults.set(timerInterval, forKey: timerIntervalKey)
        }
    }

#if os(macOS)
    private var defaults = ScreenSaverDefaults(forModuleWithName: "com.Adelsoft.Blinking-Lights-Screensaver")!
#else
    private var defaults = UserDefaults()
#endif

    private init() {
        self.defaults.register(defaults: [timerIntervalKey: 0.75])
        let savedInterval: Double = defaults.double(forKey: timerIntervalKey)
        self.timerInterval = savedInterval
    }
}

